# How to sub count of group by

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have 3 table:

```
user 1 - n (user_id)feedback(type_id) n - 1 word
```

User:

```
id name
1  name1
2  name2
3  name3
4  name4
5  name5
6  name6
```

Feedback:

```
id   user_id   type_id   title
1    1         1         title1
2    1         1         title2
3    1         2         title3
4    2         1         title4
5    2         2         title5
6    2         2         title6
7    2         1         title7
```

Word:

```
id   name         category
1    great work   FEEDBACK_TYPE
2    good work    FEEDBACK_TYPE
```

I tried to count feedback of each user with below query

Result:

```
user_id   countAllFeedback
1         3
2         4
```

Query

```
select
    feed.user_id,
    count(feed.id) as countAllFeedback
from
    feedback feed
group by
    feed.user_id;
```

I want to count feedback of each user by word name

```
user_id   countAllFeedback   countGreatWorkFeedback   countGoodWorkFeedback
1         3                   2                       1
2         4                   2                       2
```

Please help me with your Query ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below script. As you have nothing to collect dynamically from other table, No joining is required. You can use Type_ID as static logic inside CASE statement as those are known list in Word table.

```
SELECT A.user_id,
COUNT(*) countAllFeedback,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countGreatWorkFeedback,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countGoodWorkFeedback
FROM Feedback A
GROUP BY A.user_id
```

If there are possibilities of change in ID, you can do the below-

```
SELECT A.user_id,
COUNT(A.*) countAllFeedback,
SUM(CASE WHEN B.name = 'great work' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countGreatWorkFeedback,
SUM(CASE WHEN B.name = 'good work' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countGoodWorkFeedback
FROM Feedback A
INNER JOIN Word B ON A.type_id = B.id
GROUP BY A.user_id
```

Comment: This result is OK. But I think this is hacked method ^^ because when we change (delete/insert/update) in Word table. It cause Word id change, and this query will be failed :v

Comment: Values in lookup table should never be changed. You never know the range of impact of changing values in different different applications.

Comment: Anyway, I have added the option for counting using the Name Text. @TrầnThoại

Comment: Thank you, i think i will use your query for now to complete my task until i found better solution :D Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

**there is no relevance of User table (as per demo data)**

**This can achieve using this following Query....**

```
SELECT b.user_id,c.name, 
SUM(b.user_id) AS 'countAllFeedback',
SUM(CASE WHEN c.name='great work' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'countGreatWorkFeedback',
SUM(CASE WHEN c.name='good work' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'countGoodWorkFeedback'
FROM tbl_Feedback b
LEFT OUTER  JOIN
tbl_Word c
ON b.type_id=c.id
GROUP BY b.user_id,c.name
```

**Note:- Here i'm using Case statement with sum function**

Comment: Sorry, result of your query is wrong. I tested it and this is image of result

[Image result](https://imgur.com/a/VwLxDDG)

Such as with user_id 26967 i want result is only one row with: column countAllFeedback = 19, countGreatworkFeedback = 11, countGoodworkFeedback = 3